# recursive clousure error applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList) groovy

Tags: recursion, groovy

I have a list:

```
def myList = [[item1:1, values:'a'], [item2:2, values:'a'], 
     [item2:3,values:'b']]
```

My recursive clousure:

```
def getList  = {  sep, list ->

           list.each{ item ->

                //def at = it

                def da = myList.findAll { 

                    it?.value == item.value
                }
                //println da
                if(da?.size()>1 ){

                    getList(',',da)

                }
                else
                {
                    //println item.category+sep
                }



           }

          }
```

And call

```
getList(',', myList)
```

Error returns:

> No signature of method: sigec.media.MediaExpenseService.getList() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)

But find returns other list (first iteration):

```
[[item1:1, values:'a'], [item2:2, values:'a']]
```

what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `getList` variable before you define it for this to work, change

```
def getList = {  sep, list ->
```

To

```
def getList
getList = { sep, list ->
```

Comment: Thanks I never thought :D

Comment: It's a pretty common error that has to do with initialization rather than assignment.  The right-hand side of an initialization statement is resolved prior to creation of the variable on the left-hand side, so that variable can't be referenced in that statement or in closure-snapshots made during that statement.